# Rails - params.require not seeing request params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Very simply, I'm trying to submit a form using ActiveRecord enforcing params using params.require. I get the error

param is missing or the value is empty: brand_id

in my getter for the params:

```
def pb_params
    @pb_params = params.require(:brand_id).permit(:profile_id)
end
```

The request parameters are listed as

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"IArCnwg/RHEVPKVaSLshrO6ITm+k1H9C6g9a8VYSVrk=",
 "profile_brand"=>{"brand_id"=>"122",
 "profile_id"=>""},
 "commit"=>"Submit"}
```

So the data is being passed over, is in the params in the error output but isn't recognized as present. This is a junction object with two foreign keys. One is populated on the form and sent back - that is the one that's required.

Comment: `params.require(:profile_brand).permit(:brand_id, :profile_id)`. from the look at your parameters, the two attributes you want to whitelist are `brand_id` and `profile_id`, so you `permit` those.

Comment: yes, @JustinLicata that works but is there no way to require one of the foreign keys? This is a junction object, a unique combination of two other ids.

Comment: @FSDev strong-params is not for validation but for whitelisting user input. any logic that can't be expressed by declaration should go into your controller code.

Comment: Thanks - this definitely works!